# How to get specific coordinate system to get arcGIS point shapefile in r?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, r

I have a Point shapefile from arcGIS 10. I want to get it in r and also want to get it a specific predefined coordinate systen for my data. I can read the shapefile in R but summary in r Shows projectltion info like this `proj4string : [NA]' and if i want to transform the reference systen it Shows something like this:

Error in spTransform(xSP, CRSobj, ...) : 
  No transformation possible from NA reference System
What can I do to deal with this Problem. Thanks a lot:-)

Comment: I have already got the solution using rgdal package in r. the codes are as follows: "ogrInfo(".", "allpoints_ohnegs" and 2)then use the CRS´info to define projection as proj4string:-pointA.prj<-"+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs", step 3) define projection to shapefile:-pointa_proj<-SpatialPoints(pointA,  proj4string=CRS(as.character(pointA.prj)), bbox = NULL) ---done)"

Comment: I think you should write this up as an Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Cant you just simply use text to fill your proj4string. So:

First read in your shapefile calling it: pointshapefile. And then run the following line.

```
pointshapefile@proj4string <- "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs"
```

Afterwards you can use spTransform. I think R gives you a warning that you have manually changed the projection but it should work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. It worked for me..!

```R
library(sp)

shp <- shapefile("Path_To_Shapefile.shp")

proj4string(shp) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=44 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
```